# Python: How to write a single channel png file from numpy array?

Tags: python, opencv

I want to write a single channel png image from a numpy array in python?
In Matlab that would be

```
A = randi(100,100,255)
imwrite(uint8(A),'myFilename.png','png');
```

I saw exampels using `from PIL import Image`  and `Image.fromarray()` but they are for jpeg and 3-channel pngs only it appears...

I already found the solution using opencv, I will post it here. Hopefully it will shorten someone else's searching...

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imsave.html

Comment: that solution would be for rgb, but I need single channel

Comment: If you hand it a single channel, it writes a single channel. See the first example, it's a bw gradient.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a solution using opencv / cv2

```
import cv2
myImg = np.random.randint(255, size=(200, 400)) # create a random image
cv2.imwrite('myImage.png',myImg)
```

Comment: warning: `cv2.imwrite()` uses BGR as the default order of columns, and so can mess with the intended color of the image

Answer (score 6):

PIL's `Image.fromarray()` automatically determines the [mode](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.x/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes) to use [from the datatype](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/0764b2b/PIL/Image.py#L2245) of the passed numpy array, for example for an 8-bit greyscale image you can use:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

data = np.random.randint(256, size=(100, 100), dtype=np.uint8)
img = Image.fromarray(data)  # uses mode='L'
```

This however only works if your array uses a compatible datatype, if you simply use `data = np.random.randint(256, size=(100, 100))` that can result in a int64 array (typestr `<i8`), which PIL can't handle.

You can also specify a different mode, e.g. to interpret a 32bit array as an RGB image:

```
data = np.random.randint(2**32, size=(100, 100), dtype=np.uint32)
img = Image.fromarray(data, mode='RGB')
```

Internally [`Image.fromarray()`](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/0764b2b/PIL/Image.py#L2179) simply tries to guess the correct mode and size and then invokes `Image.frombuffer()`.

The image can then be saved as any format `PIL` [can handle](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.x/handbook/image-file-formats.html) e.g: [`img.save('filename.png')`](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.save)

Answer (score 2):

You might want not to utilise OpenCV for simple image manipulation. As suggested, use PIL:

```
im = Image.fromarray(arr)
im.save("output.png", "PNG")
```

Have you tried this? What has failed here that led you to concluding that this is JPEG-only?

Comment: this saves a 3 channel pnd, but I need a 1 channel png file

Comment: Then you need your array to be of type uint8.
im = Image.fromarray(arr.astype(numpy.uint8))